# Is it possible modify the mpd with URLs which points php code instead of video segments?

Tags: php, video-streaming, mpeg-dash

this is a part of my mpd:

```
<SegmentList>
    <Initialization sourceURL="bbbh_init.mp4"/>
   </SegmentList>
   <Representation id="3" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4d401f" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="24" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="973441" accessTech="unicast">
    <SegmentList timescale="1000" duration="2000">

    <!-- <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_1.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_2.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_3.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_4.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_5.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_6.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_7.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_8.m4s"/> -->

    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=1"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=2"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=3"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=4"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=5"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=6"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=7"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=8"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=9"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=10"/>
```

If I use the commented lines, where I get video segments requesting them to the server, it works fine.

```
    <!-- <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_1.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_2.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_3.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_4.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_5.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_6.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_7.m4s"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_8.m4s"/> -->
```

I am trying to read a segmentURL getting a video segment via php code, but it doesnt work, with this lines of my mpd code:

```
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=1"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=2"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=3"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=4"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=5"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=6"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=7"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=8"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=9"/>
    <SegmentURL media="https://www.dash.com/cgi.php/?pflag=0&segment=10"/>
```

Is there any way to get the video segments the way I want?
Via php? I have the php code, and it works fine, because when I make a request from my browser it do what I want, but when the dash read the mpd and the client requests the php code, the client has not response.

I think that the problem is that I am using the SegmentURL tag not properly, because I am not passing a video in a direct way, I am passing a php code that sends the video sengment when I execute it.

Thank you so much!!

This is the php code. If i execute this code in the browser, it downloads the file, but not from the mpd. When the browser downloads the file, it gives an http code 204, which means no content. How could I solve it?
The variable $segment is just a number of a segment.

```
$file = '/bbbhewma/dash_bbbh1000k_' . $segment . '.m4s';

if (file_exists('/usr/local/apache2/www/dash/CUSUM-dashjs13' . $file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('accept-ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a client perspective, this should definitely work. The client does not know whether the server returns the segment directly or via a script. That's why I think the problem is in the PHP script or the server configuration.

Hard to say without access to the script and/or stream, but one reason for the problem might be that the script does not return the correct HTTP status code (i.e. 200). Another reason might be that the MIME type of the returned segment is not set accordingly (e.g. "video/mp4"). Maybe the content of the returned segment gets corrupted by the PHP script. Without more information, only guesses can be made.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have updated the question with the php code.

Comment: Hey Daniel, you are right. It works, I have problems in the mpd, which is an xml, and i was using the "&" in a wrong way... But what you said is correct.